# SQL Query to retrieve values inside tags(child nodes) from a XML data in SnowFlake

Tags: sql, xml, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a XML(edited) File with the following data:

```
<dept dept_id="1" dept_name="Marketing">
     <progress>1</progress>
    <employee empname="a">
         <end> 1 </end>
        <address addr1="123 abc">
        ...
        </address>
    </employee>
</dept>
<dept dept_id="2" dept_name="Sales">
    <progress>1</progress>
    <employee empname="b">
        <end> 1 </end>
        <address addr1="456 cde">
        ...
        </address>
    </employee>
</dept>
```

I put this file in AWS S3 and then used 'copy into' to transfer this data into a external table in snowflake in a variant column. Like Below:

```
  copy into DB.AWS_S3_STAGE_SCHEMA.test_XML_copy
  from @AWS_S3_LANDING/websiteXML/Test_xml.xml
  FILE_FORMAT = ( TYPE =  XML STRIP_OUTER_ELEMENT = TRUE  )  ;
```

Now, I can query the data from this table and retrieve data like 'marketing' and 'sales', which are inside tags using the following query(I got the syntax from snowflake docs and used it. ):

```
SELECT
    GET(xmldata, '@dept_id')::integer as dept_id,
    GET(xmldata, '@dept_name')::string as dept_name
FROM test_XML_copy;
```

But, I cannot query the data inside tags which are in child nodes. For example: I need data like 'a' and '123 abc'.
If anybody can help me in this query, that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a combination of [`XMLGET`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/xmlget.html) and [`GET`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/get.html) functions to traverse nested objects in an XML document.

The former helps fetch an entire tag object found below the current tag, while the latter allows querying attributes and regular values within the current tag.

```sql
SELECT
    -- <dept> (root)
    GET(xmldata, '@dept_id')::integer as dept_id,
    GET(xmldata, '@dept_name')::string as dept_name,
    -- <dept>.<employee>
    GET(XMLGET(xmldata, 'employee'), '@empname')::string as employee_name,
    -- <dept>.<employee>.<address>
    GET(XMLGET(XMLGET(xmldata, 'employee'), 'address'), '@addr1')::string as address_1
FROM test_XML_copy;
```

Which should yield:

```sh
+---------+-----------+---------------+-----------+                             
| DEPT_ID | DEPT_NAME | EMPLOYEE_NAME | ADDRESS_1 |
|---------+-----------+---------------+-----------|
|       1 | Marketing | a             | 123 abc   |
|       2 | Sales     | b             | 456 def   |
| ...     | ...       | ...           | ...       |
+---------+-----------+---------------+-----------+
```

Your example data shows no repetition of child tags, but if they do repeat (such as multiple `employee` in each `dept`) [then `FLATTEN` can first be used to produce one `employee` per row](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62073635/13472370) and the above approach can be reapplied. Alternatively, if it is a fixed form of tag structure and they are always ordered, you can use the instance number in `XMLGET` to point to each one (implicit default is 0, the first object).

An example that explodes the document into one row per employee and per address inner tags:

```sql
SELECT
xmldata:"@dept_id"::integer as dept_id,
xmldata:"@dept_name"::string as dept_name,
emp.value:"@empname"::string as employee_name,
addr.value:"@addr1"::string as address_1
FROM
test_XML_copy,
LATERAL FLATTEN(xmldata:"$") emp,
LATERAL FLATTEN(emp.value:"$") addr
WHERE emp.value:"@" = 'employee' AND addr.value:"@" = 'address';
```

(This yields results similar to the above, for the example provided in OP's question)

**Note**: You can also use the [path syntax](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/get_path.html) with `$` and `@` characters to navigate the structure instead of nesting functions, but these rely on strict ordering of the input data structure:

```sql
-- See outer / inner structures in 'JSON' form
SELECT
    xmldata:"@" dept_tag,
    xmldata:"$" dept_tag_contents
FROM test_XML_copy;

-- Sample equivalent query using path expressions, relying on ordering:
SELECT
    xmldata:"@dept_id",
    xmldata:"@dept_name",
    xmldata:"$"[1]."@empname",
    xmldata:"$"[1]."$"[1]."@addr1"
FROM test_XML_copy;
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. kind off what i was looking for. But as you mentioned there is data repitition. I tried using lateral but doesn't work. can you check out please for the following XML.

Comment: ```
<dept dept_id="1" dept_name="Marketing">
     <progress>1</progress>
    <employee empname='a'>
         <end> 1 </end>
        <address addr1='123 abc'>
        ...
        </address>
    </employee>
</dept>
<dept dept_id="2" dept_name="Sales">
    <progress>1</progress>
    <employee empname='b'>
  <end> 1 </end>
        <address addr1='456 cde'>
        ...
        </address>
    </employee>
</dept>
```

Comment: Hi Harsh,
Yes, employee and address tag does repeat. I have updated the XML File in the main question. I tried using a combination of Lateral, XMLGET, GET but doesn't seem to be working. Check following query:

Comment: SELECT
    -- <dept> (root)
    GET(xmldata, '@dept_id')::integer as dept_id,
    GET(xmldata, '@dept_name')::string as dept_name,
    -- <dept>.<employee>
    GET(XMLGET(div.value, 'employee'), '@empname')::string as employee_name,
    -- <dept>.<employee>.<address>
    GET(XMLGET(XMLGET(sub.value, 'employee'), 'address'), '@addr1')::string as address_1
FROM test_XML_copy
,  lateral FLATTEN( xmldata:"$" ) div
,  lateral FLATTEN( div.value:"$" ) sub

Comment: Thanks man. Exactly what i was looking for. 
I did ask Snowflake support the same question and they came back with huge queries(9 flattens) and did another big query for repeating tag values and asked us to join them by using temp tables in between. And that query isn't even working lol.

Answer (score 0):

To extract data from the child nodes you will need to use LATERAL FLATTEN to transform the data, e.g. to flatten the `<employee>` element and get the `emp_name` attribute:

```
select
       XMLGET( xmldata, '@dept_id' ):"$"::string AS dept_id
     , XMLGET( xmldata, '@dept_name' ):"$"::string AS dept_name
     , XMLGET( emp.value, '@empname' ):"$"::string as empname
from
    test_XML_copy
    ,  lateral FLATTEN(test_XML_copy.xmldata:"$") emp
  where emp.value like '<employee>%'
  order by dept_id, empname;
```

This article has some very useful info on querying XML in Snowflake: https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Querying-Nested-XML-in-Snowflake

Comment: Hi nathan,
Appreciate your reponse. Looks like you got this query straight from the snowflake community. I have read through all the docs and communities. Even used lateral to flatten. Lateral flatten and XMLGET is useful to get child node values but not child node tag values. That is why I posted here.

Comment: I adapted the linked example so that it matched the example data in your question. Lateral Flatten is definitely what you need to use to unpack nested XML or json, the answer above shows you how to do this and get the element attributes as per the question. If this isn't what you want then please edit your question to clarify, ideally show what you have tried that isn't working.