# Snowflake:How to read the data which is in JSON format but it is wrapped in an XML response

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I get the data response from API as XML with JSON data in it

How can I achieve reading the JSON data using Snowflake to load into the table?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <GetFilteredResponse xmlns="Log_EngIP">
            <GetFilteredCustomReportResult>
                <DtoObject>
                    <ReportData>[{"ID":1,"Name":"Default","OwnerID":1,"SortOrder":null,"Terms":"+0"},{"ID":3,"Name":"VIP","OwnerID":1,"SortOrder":null,"Terms":"+30"},{"ID":9,"Name":"Telesphere (EmailAndStatus)","OwnerID":1,"SortOrder":0,"Terms":"+0"},{"ID":10,"Name":"Default","OwnerID":693,"SortOrder":null,"Terms":"+30"}]</ReportData>
                    <NumberOfPages>1</NumberOfPages>
                </DtoObject>
                <Response>Successful</Response>
                <Successful>true</Successful>
            </GetFilteredCustomReportResult>
        </GetFilteredResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [parse](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/parse_xml.html)/[load](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html#type-xml) the XML, use [XML traversal functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62070071/sql-query-to-retrieve-values-inside-tagschild-nodes-from-a-xml-data-in-snowfla/62079920#62079920) to extract the `ReportData` element value (a JSON string), re-parse the JSON [as a variant](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/parse_json.html), then query its fields using [JSON traversal functions](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-semistructured.html).

Here's a simple example that assumes the sample provided is positional:

```sql
with tbl as (
-- Sample 'table' with 1 row of XML-parsed variant data
  select parse_xml('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><GetFilteredResponse xmlns="Log_EngIP"><GetFilteredCustomReportResult><DtoObject><ReportData>[{"ID":1,"Name":"Default","OwnerID":1,"SortOrder":null,"Terms":"+0"},{"ID":3,"Name":"VIP","OwnerID":1,"SortOrder":null,"Terms":"+30"},{"ID":9,"Name":"Telesphere (EmailAndStatus)","OwnerID":1,"SortOrder":0,"Terms":"+0"},{"ID":10,"Name":"Default","OwnerID":693,"SortOrder":null,"Terms":"+30"}]</ReportData><NumberOfPages>1</NumberOfPages></DtoObject><Response>Successful</Response><Successful>true</Successful></GetFilteredCustomReportResult></GetFilteredResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>') xmlv

), first_report_data_json as (

-- Extracting JSON as a string value from XML and then reparsing it as its own variant
-- This uses the symbol style of traversal, but XMLGET/GET can alternatively be used
  select parse_json(xmlv:"$"."$"."$"."$"[0]."$"[0]."$") jsonv from tbl

)
-- Producing rows from the JSON array variant formed above
select e.value:ID, e.value:Name from first_report_data_json, lateral flatten(first_report_data_json.jsonv) e;
```

Which yields:

```
+------------+-------------------------------+                                  
| E.VALUE:ID | E.VALUE:NAME                  |
|------------+-------------------------------|
| 1          | "Default"                     |
| 3          | "VIP"                         |
| 9          | "Telesphere (EmailAndStatus)" |
| 10         | "Default"                     |
+------------+-------------------------------+
```

**Note**: The access of XML nodes `GetFilteredCustomReportResult` and further required array-style access (`"$"[0]`) likely because the schema (readable in the `xmlns` links) defining it [allows for unbounded number of occurrences](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#OccurrenceConstraints) (i.e. its actually an array of elements, not necessarily a singular one).

In a real-world situation, to be complete, you'll use `FLATTEN` to break them out to their own whole rows for independent processing. I've omitted that here and just gone after the single element existing in the example provided.

Comment: Can you explain to me why you gave `"$"[0]`

Comment: When the XML file is one line it works fine but if xml file looks like mutliple line with each tag format , it gives error as `Error parsing XML: not an XML element File`